# Are US ISPs and firms using Chinese registered IPv4 numbers on their routing infrastructure in the US?

Tags: router, ip

Chinese owned/registered IP addresses are appearing within my US ISP routing infrastructure from a trace route. ISP says they are leasing them from China. Has anyone run into this before? With all of IPv4 taken is this "new" normal practice to use foreign registered IP addresses in the US?

Comment: "*ISP says they are leasing them from China*" sorta answers the title question, does it not?

Comment: @Ricky Beam, stick around, you'll have an ISP lie to you yet. YLearn's comment on Teun Vink's answer increases my suspicion of the practice (and should surprise no-one), making this a useful question.

Comment: Of course they lie, but in this case, it's close enough to the truth.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

That's becoming more and more normal. IPv4 blocks are being leased and traded all over the world due to the lack of unassigned IPv4 blocks at most RIRs.

Comment: Although it should be noted that this practice is often a violation of the transfer policy of the RIRs and may cause the IP assignment to be revoked by the issuing RIR.  There are many organizations who have "bought" IP address space from third parties only to have it re-assigned by the RIR.

Comment: References? I've not heard of anyone revoking an assignment. (mostly because if's a huge pain in the ass, and simply not worth the effort and expense.) Why do you think ARIN never reclaimed all those sparsely used /8 "legacy" allocations. (answer: legal cost, and utter futility of it as we'll still have the same problem a few months later. John Currin said as much, numerous times. [eg. on NANOG])